# Copy task in Gradle says "UP TO DATE" on first attempt

Tags: gradle, task, build.gradle

I have a copy task that is trying to copy files extracted in the 'dependsOn' task.  The destination folder contains a timestamp which is retrieved from a properties file.

```
task copyFilesToBuild(type: Copy, dependsOn:unzipExtFile) {
    def tmpTimestampFile = file("$buildDir/tmp/timestamp.properties")
    if (tmpTimestampFile.exists()) {
        stampProp = new Properties()
        stampProp.load(new FileInputStream(tmpTimestampFile))
        def timestampFromFile=stampProp.getProperty('propfileTimestamp')
        def unzippedExtFilesDir = file("$buildDir/tmp/unzipped/static/js/app")
        def appBuildDir = file("$buildDir/apptmp/war/app/app_$timestampFromFile/sub")
        from unzippedExtFilesDir
        into appBuildDir
    }
}
```

First time through my build (after a clean) it says 'UP TO DATE" (debug output says it's skipping the task as it has no source files.)

I have tried adding closures to defer evaluation, (*from { unzippedExtFilesDir }*) and tried putting the body of the task in a doFirst, but neither had any effect.  I've also tried using the dependsOn task name (unzipExtFile) directly in the 'from' statement but that also did not work.

Second time the build is run this task does get run, so it appears to be a timing thing between the configuration and execution, but I'm running out of ideas.  Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is reading the timestamp at configuration time, before any task has run. (You can see this by adding a `println` statement.) Because no timestamp file exists at this time (in particular on the first run), no source location (`from ...`) gets configured, and the task is considered up-to-date because there is nothing to copy. Putting the whole timestamp logic into the `into` block (`into { ...; appBuildDir }`) should solve the problem.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.  The message Gradle puts out about 'no source files' is very misleading when it's the target folder that is tripping things up.  I didn't know you could add that kind of tail in the 'into' block.  Are there any comprehensive Gradle syntax guides out there?

Comment: "no source files" means that there are no source files/dirs, not that there is no target dir. The concrete build language is documented in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html). Some of the general "mechanics" of the build language are documented in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: the difference between `from  location` and `from {location}` is that the lather configures the location with a closure whereas the first one with a location directly. The closure is evaluated just in time.